# How exactly do I make money with AdMob?

Tags: admob

I have AdMob ads in my app, and there are things that still are not clear to me. I have searched a long time on the internet, and many people say different things.

I know I make money when people click on my ads . But do I make money by impressions as well, or only clicks. Many guys says if there is no clicks, there is no money. Say I have 1 000 000 impressions daily, but no clicks. I then make zero money?

Also some people are saying if you have a lot of impressions, you don´t make much money if people click on your ads. Lets say App Nr.1 has got 1 000 000 impression daily and 100 clicks daily, and App Nr.2. has got only 10 000 impressions daily but the same number of clicks. Which app makes more money on their clicks?

Do my fill rate have anything to say on what I make on impressions? It says: ***Additionally, the number of impressions may be lower if your app preloads ads. For example, if an app sends an ad request when it opens, but only shows that ad to users if certain criteria are met, such as reaching a specified level. If a user doesn't meet the criteria, the ad will not be shown and will report no impressions for that request.***  My app preloads most of its ads, for example when my interstitial that is being shown when a user has made a turn in my TurnBased game is being closed by the user, I load a new interstitial right away. I do it so the ad is "available" when another turn is being made, which Admob Guide Lines advised me to do. Will this "hurt" my revenue in any way?

Comment: Surely AdMob must document how you earn money from your ads.

Answer (score 1):

This has been answers **many** times.

Generally you are only paid for the clicks on ads.

If you generate a **really** large number of impressions then you might also get paid something for your impressions.

Fill rate is just the percentage of time that an ad was available to you when you requested it. There may not always be an ad available to your user, because of current ad market, their location, time of day, type of device they are using. It is a good idea to use mediation to ensure that if one ad network has no ad that another is asked. This can ensure a 100% fill rate. Which means you are showing ads 100% of the time that you could.

Gaming the system is not a good idea. Google run all kinds of analysis over your requests, impressions, clicks. When (not if) you are caught you will have your account banned.